# NativeScript geolocation in the background

Tags: nativescript

My use case is the following - being able to periodically send updates to a web service with the current location of the device on which the {NS} app is running. This should happen **even if the app is "minimized"**.
I saw that [workers](http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model#multithreading-model) have been added to the framework, but as I understand it, the app is supposed to be active(not minimized) for the worker to execute.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Cheers

Comment: I'm currently developing an app using this plugin: https://github.com/transistorsoft/nativescript-background-geolocation-lt. It can track in the background even if the app is terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The plugin looks amazing - you can tell a lot of effort went in developing that, but I want to test the prototype first on Android and 300$ seems bit steep atm :)

Comment: Clone the repo and look at the code for the demo app. You can use the licence key to test on android as long as you use the same package name that the demo app uses.

Comment: I am struggle solving this problem, especially in {N} - iOS. I created a CustomAppDelegate and when home button is pressed I see the code is working but I am not able to get the localization or send data to the server. @JoroTenev did you resolve it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use background-services for this purpose.
[NativeScriptBackgroundServices](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript)

Comment: Please add some content from your link to your answer. Thanks!